# How to use @Html.Raw in swal message

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to pass controller html msg to view swal pop-up box but it's showing html code not html formated msg - like this:

[image: here is output]

Controller code :

```
ViewBag.message = "<h3> Something went terribly wrong, please try again or contact us at <a href='mailto:info@abc.we'>info@abc.we</a> </h3>";
```

View markup:

```
@{
    var msg = Html.Raw(ViewBag.message);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
                swal({
                    title: "@Html.Raw(msg)",
                    text: "",
                    icon: "success",
                    button: "Ok",
                });
            });
</script>
```

This is my code - can anyone please help me find a solution? I am stuck on this problem.

I just want controller html msg to be displayed properly in swal pop-up.

Thanks in advance to whoever is able to help me with this problem.

Another Example :

**Controller** :

ViewBag.htmlmsg = "alert('asd');";

**View** :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlmsg);
        
});
</script>
```

this one is also not working. not showing alert pop-up.

Comment: Do you know `swal` CDN link so that it can be reproduce?

Comment: i didn't get your point swal pop-up working fine i just want to output like if i add <a> tag in viewbag i will be work on view page as url. how can i do this ? @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: I got your point, please try the soltuion , it will generate expected output.

Comment: Did you tried the solution ? Does it work as expected?

Comment: sorry for late replay but your solution isn't worked. i have make another example but it still not working. see above updated code. @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Could you please explain, what exactly not working? What are you getting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want controller html msg to be displayed properly in swal
> pop-up.

Well, `swal` alert has the `content` attribute to allow `htmlContent` you can use that as well. In that case you could set additional `span` and bind your `viewbag` there, which will generate expected result.

**Controller:**

```
public class RawHtmlController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            ViewBag.message = "<h3> Something went terribly wrong, please try again or contact us at <a href='mailto:info@abc.we'>info@abc.we</a> </h3>";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Script:**

```
@{
   

}


@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
           
            var message = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)";

            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = message;
           

            $(function () {
                swal({
                    content: span,
                    icon: "success",
                    button: "Ok",
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
        }
```

**Your Scenario:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                var message = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)";
    
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.innerHTML = message;
                   $(function () {
                    swal({
                        content: span,
                        icon: "success",
                        button: "Ok",
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

**Output:**

[image]